# Connect working Binding to a List<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am binding to a property of an object `CaptureNamesList`. The variable I need to bind to is a `List<string>`.

It doesn't work when I bind straight to the `List<string>`. I created a wrapper class for strings, `StringWrapper`, and it works when I use the `List<StringWrapper>` _test4 as a backing variable. However, I need to somehow link this back to _test1. My attempt is shown commented out, but it doesn't seem to work.

How do I bind to this `List<string>` ?

xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CaptureNamesList}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

c#:

```
public List<StringWrapper> CaptureNamesList
    {
        get { return _test4; }
        set { _test4 = value; }
        //get { return StringWrapper.castList(_test1); }
        //set { _test1 = StringWrapper.castBackList(value); }
    }

private List<StringWrapper> _test4 = StringWrapper.castList(new List<string> { "one", "two" });
private List<string> _test1 = new List<string> { "one", "two" };
```

The wrapper class for strings:

```
public class StringWrapper
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    static public explicit operator StringWrapper(string value)
    {
        return new StringWrapper() {Value=value};
    }
    static public explicit operator string(StringWrapper value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }

    public static List<StringWrapper> castList(List<string> strings)
    {
        List<StringWrapper> wrappers = new List<StringWrapper>();
        strings.ForEach(item => wrappers.Add((StringWrapper)item));
        return wrappers;
    }

    public static List<string> castBackList(List<StringWrapper> wrappers)
    {
        List<string> strings = new List<string>();
        strings.ForEach(item => strings.Add((string)item));
        return strings;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to a `List<string>` should be exactly the same, except that in your `DataTemplate` you don't have to specify any property for the binding:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CaptureNamesList}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: So the code behind would be: 'public List<string> CaptureNamesList { get { return _test1; } set { _test1 = value; } }' 'private List<string> _test1 = new List<string> { "one", "two" };' Doesn't bind.

Comment: What does `doesn't bind` mean? Do you have an error on your `output` window? Is there an exception? Is the DataContext set properly? I use this exact code snippet for plenty of my bindings to `List<string>` . The only thing I can think of here if it doesn't bind is that your `DataContext` isn't properly set. Can you check the output window if there is anything?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I mean when I run it the values shows up but when I change them It doesn't seem to change the value of the _test1 (btw I added Path=. to make it compile)

Comment: If you want any `ItemsControl` to be synchronized to their source lists, you need to use `ObservableCollection` (which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` ) rather than `List` . A `List` doesn't notify for its changes, so the view has no way of knowing it has to update. Replace your list by an `ObservableCollection` and it should work fine

Comment: so this? `public ObservableCollection<string> CaptureNamesList {get { return new ObservableCollection<string>(_test1); } set { _test1 = value.ToList(); }`    This doesn't seem to update either. I am stuck with the private variable being a `List<string>` as I'm inheriting from my backend.

        }

Comment: In this case, nothing stops you from working UI-side with your `ObservableCollection` and then defer any change to the underlying `List`. You should create a spare `ObservableCollection` to work with. Check out this article for some help synchronizing lists if needed: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62537/M-V-VM-How-to-keep-collections-of-ViewModel-and-Mo

Answer (score 1):

If you're binding a collection to your XAML, i suggest you use `ObservableCollection<string>`

```
public ObservableCollection<string> CaptureNamesList { get; set; }
```

Im not sure why you'd want to bind a list to a TextBox, maybe what you need is a TextBlock or ListView to show the items in a collection.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CaptureNamesList}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```